# How can I access the name of the T4 output file via code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4, texttemplate

Visual Studio's T4 templates offer the [Output Directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/gg586943(v=vs.110)) which allows me to specify the file extension of the generated file as follows:

```
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
```

I would like to access that file extension from the code within the T4 template so that I can get the entire filename of the file that is generated. I can get the name of the T4 template itself via `Host` property as follows:

```cs
string templateName = Path.GetFileName(Host.TemplateFile);
```

But I don't see how to get the file extension or entire name of the T4 output file ("MyTemplate.cs" in that case if the T4 is named "MyTemplate.tt"). I can't find any property on the `Host` that seems helpful here. Does anyone know?

Comment: Can't you just use `Path.ChangeExtension(Host.TemplateFile, ".cs")`?

Comment: I've written a `.ttinclude` file containing common functionality used by several T4 templates. That `.ttinclude` file is unaware of the file extension that is defined by the including T4 template. It should just be able to get it from the parent, not set it. So, I cannot use `Path.ChangeExtension(Host.TemplateFile, ".cs")`.

Comment: Maybe you should add this information to your question.